# Grunt CSS minifier call stack exceeded

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

First time using grunt. Been able to concat and minify some javascript. When I attempt to do the same thing with CSS I get the following error:

```
λ git master* → grunt cssmin
Running "cssmin:css" (cssmin) task
>> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Warning: CSS minification failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Why could this be happening?

package.json

```
{
    "name" : "Thing",
    "title" : "Concatentation + Minification",
    "version" : "1.0.0",
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "0.4.5",
        "grunt-contrib-concat": "0.5.0",
        "grunt-contrib-cssmin" : "0.10.0",
        "grunt-contrib-watch" : "0.6.1",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify" : "0.5.0"
    }
}
```

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        concat: {
            css: {
                src: [
                    'static/css/*'
                ],
                dest: 'combined.css'
            },
            js : {
                src : [
                    'static/js/*'
                ],
                dest : 'combined.js'
            }
        },
        cssmin : {
            css:{
                src: 'combined.css',
                dest: 'combined.min.css'
            }
        },
        uglify : {
            js: {
                files: {
                    'combined.js' : [ 'combined.js' ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'concat:css'
                                  , 'cssmin:css'
                                  , 'concat:js'
                                  , 'uglify:js'
                                  ]);
};
```

Comment: `call stack exceeded` usually means infinite recursion. Based on your gruntfile I believe you should not setup output file the same as input in `uglify` section. UPD: just noticed that build halts on CSS minification, so uglify is not the reason of issue.

Comment: Your code works perfectly on my system...
Can you give a little more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had .png's in my css folder, so a call stack size exceeded was being thrown.

Comment: ah snap! was the code still working without my changes though?

Comment: interesting... there seems to be some standard ways to leverage grunt packages and that seemed to be one of these cases even though the doc said otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying the `cssmin` and `ulgify` methods as:

```
cssmin : {
    css:{
        src: '<%= concat.css.dest %>',
        dest: 'combined.min.css'
    }
},
uglify : {
    js: {
        files: {
            '<%= concat.js.dest %>' : 'combined.js'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually minify, no whitespace is removed

Answer (score 1):

Check out the structure of the cssmin task --> [cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin)

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        concat: {
            css: {
                src: [
                    'static/css/*'
                ],
                dest: 'combined.css'
            },
            js : {
                src : [
                    'static/js/*'
                ],
                dest : 'combined.js'
            }
        },
        cssmin : {
            combine: {
                 files: {
                      'combined.min.css': ['combined.css'] //<---- Looks like it was a error in the usage of grunt-contrib-cssmin
                 }
            }
        },

      uglify : {
            js: {
                files: {
                    'combined.js' : [ 'combined.min.js' ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'concat:css'
                                  , 'cssmin:css'
                                  , 'concat:js'
                                  , 'uglify:js'
                                  ]);
};
```

Comment: it's an issue with the css though, this change seems like a javascript change

Comment: indeed it does.... i am not completely sure - i will have a better look at your structure now.

Comment: you have a few ways to minify files and it simply looks like you were using a wrong syntax. Check out the above changes!

Comment: I made your changes and still receive "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" when I run `grunt cssmin`